# TypeError: Invalid data type 'str' when using DataLoader to train SciBERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am trying to perform k-fold cross validation with SciBERT, using a dataset with 2 columns: `'text'` and `'label'`. My current dataset is looking like this, as a DataFrame from pandas:
[image]

Here is the code I used for loading dataset, and performing k-fold cross validation:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
k_folds = 5
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=k_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Define a custom PyTorch dataset
class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, texts, labels):
        self.texts = texts
        self.labels = labels
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.texts[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        encoding = tokenizer(text, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors='pt')
        input_ids = encoding['input_ids'].squeeze()
        attention_mask = encoding['attention_mask'].squeeze()
        return {'input_ids': input_ids, 'attention_mask': attention_mask, 'labels': torch.tensor(label)}

# Convert dataframe to dataset
dataset = TextDataset(data['text'].tolist(), data['label'].tolist())

from torch.optim import AdamW
from tqdm import tqdm
from statistics import mean


fold_accuracies = []


# Perform k-fold cross-validation
for fold, (train_indices, val_indices) in enumerate(skf.split(data['text'], data['label'])):
    print(f"Training Fold {fold+1}/{k_folds}")
    # Split dataset into train and validation sets for the current fold
    train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, train_indices)
    val_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, val_indices)
    print(train_dataset)
    # Create data loaders
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
    print(type(train_loader))
    # Training loop
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, eps=1e-8)
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    model.to(device)
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(6):  # Adjust the number of epochs as needed
        epoch_losses = []
        for batch in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
            attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
            labels = batch['labels'].to(device)
            outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
            loss = outputs.loss
            epoch_losses.append(loss.item())
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        print(f"epoch {epoch + 1} loss: {mean(epoch_losses)}")
```

However, when I tried to train the model, I got `TypeError: new(): invalid data type str()` from my notebook. I think that could be because my label could not be converted to a tensor, however, I tried `tf.convert_to_tensor()`, as well as `torch.FloatTensor()`, but the problem is still not resolved.

[image: tensor]

So, what could be the potential solution for this problem, to ensure that I could run the training process?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess looking at the code is your labels are string values, so `{'labels': torch.tensor(label)}` is throwing the error. Add a preprocessing step where labels are mapped to integer values.

Comment: Yeah, I asked the author of this code, and she said that I would need to encode the data as well (using LabelEncoder for this code is the right choice).

Comment: Yes, you can use the sklearn LabelEncoder to convert the string labels into numeric labels.